# Rails: Adding Sidekiq Debounce to Middleware Chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am trying to debounce Sidekiq jobs in my Rails app. The [Sidekiq Debounce docs](https://github.com/hummingbird-me/sidekiq-debounce) say:

> Add Sidekiq::Debounce to your client middleware chain

What does this mean? How do I add this to my middleware chain in a rails app?

Answer (score 0):

In config/application.rb add `config.middleware.use Sidekiq::Debounce`.  You can see more options for adding middleware here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Comment: Adding that line gives me an error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `initialize'" I've added in my Application class